# Regular Expression in Python using re.split and pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this:

`string ='ArcelorMittal invests =E2=82=AC87m in new process that cuts emissions=20'`

I want to take out `=E2=82=AC` and `=20`

But when I use,

```
pattern ='(=\w\w)+'
a=re.split(pattern,string)
```

it returns

```
['ArcelorMittal invests ', '=AC', '87m in new process that cuts emissions', '=20', '']
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `re.findall`

```
>>> s = 'ArcelorMittal invests =E2=82=AC87m in new process that cuts emissions=20'
>>> re.findall(r'(?:=\w{2})+', s)
['=E2=82=AC', '=20']
>>>
```

Use `re.sub` if you want to remove those chars.

```
>>> re.sub(r'(?:=\w{2})+', '', s)
'ArcelorMittal invests 87m in new process that cuts emissions'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help, but I need to decode it then put them back later so I want to use an order array so I can join them after decode

Comment: I think you need to use `re.sub`

Comment: thanks a lot avinash, I was extracting this text from gmail and they have some encoding problem , so I was gonna convert =E2=82=AC to /xE2/x82/xAC, then encode it to utf-8, then put back to the original string. Is there any way to work on it? thanks a lot

Comment: just replace `=` with `/x` . And also you may use re.split with your original but you have to turn capturing group to non-capturing group `pattern =r'(?:=\w\w)+'`, so that it won't capture the delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31400502/regular-expression-in-python-using-re-split-and-pattern#comment50775851_31400525) I would recommend you to use [`quopri.decodestring`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/quopri.html) on original string. There is no need to extract these characters and decode them separately

```
>>> import quopri
>>> s = 'ArcelorMittal invests =E2=82=AC87m in new process that cuts emissions=20'
>>> quopri.decodestring(s)
'ArcelorMittal invests \xe2\x82\xac87m in new process that cuts emissions '
>>> print quopri.decodestring(s)
ArcelorMittal invests €87m in new process that cuts emissions
```